# Plugin for Joomla website

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to find a solution to connect my website created by Joomla CMS to other websites using REST calls and APIs. after searching on net, a friend suggest me to create a plugin that can do this.

Is there any plugin that can i add into my Joomla website in order to let my website do some REST calls (GET, POST ...) ?
Can someone help me please?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Hint: This is not one of them

Comment: okey i'm sorry for that

Comment: Read the Joomla documentation and then ask for help on the joomla.stackexchange.com site.